# How would I compile and run code when an application is opened?

Tags: vb.net

I am getting data from a webpage with vb.net code on it and currently have it being sent to a RichTextBox. How would I compile and run the code when the application starts?

Comment: You're looking for Roslyn.  However, beware of security issues.

Comment: This can also be done without Roslyn. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12852/Compile-and-Run-VB-NET-Code-using-the-CodeDom